# My maui app throws exception if I open second window and close it then attempt to displayalert

Tags: .net, maui, windowing

in my app adding new client will display alert that tells the user that the new client is added successfully and it works fine but after opening a second window (displays a client info) and  closing it attempting to add new client throws an exception (the client is added to the database successfully but the exception is thrown at displaying the alert)

The exception

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in WinRT.Runtime.dll
WinRT information: The WinUI Desktop Window object has already been closed.
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
WinRT information: The WinUI Desktop Window object has already been closed.
The program '[77340] VetOrg.exe' has exited with code 3221226107 (0xc000027b).
```

This is how I open Second window

```
 public async void GetOwnerInfo()
        {
            Window window = new Window(new ClientView(new ClientViewModel(db, SelectedOwner)));

            Application.Current.OpenWindow(window);
                
        }
```

This is How I display alert

```
 await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Done", AppRes.DoneOwnerPetComplaint, AppRes.Ok);
```

I expected the display alert to work fine since the main window is still open and.

Comment: You can try to update your libraries of your app and try again.